# Are these divergence proofs correct?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Show from the definition that each of the following are divergent:
>   a) $a_n = (-1)^n+\frac 1n$
>   b) $b_n = \frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}$
>   c) $c_n = i^n + \frac{1}{2^n}$

I just want to make sure that my proofs are correct and "elegant".  Note that these proofs are supposed to use the definition of convergence and not more advanced stuff like the Cauchy criterion or subsequences or whatever.

**Part a)**

By negating the definition of convergence of a sequence we find the condition for divergence of the sequence $s_n$ to be

$$\forall L\in\Bbb C\ \exists \epsilon\gt 0\ \forall N\in\Bbb N\ \exists n\ge N\ :\ |s_n - L| \ge \epsilon$$

Consider $L\ge 0$.  For all odd $n\gt 1$, $a_n = -1+\frac 1n \lt 0$ and consequently $|a_n-L|\gt 0$.  Let $\epsilon = \frac{|a_n-L|}{2}$ for some odd $n\ge N\gt 1$.  Then $|a_n-L|\ge \epsilon\gt 0$ as required.
Now consider $L\lt 0$.  For all even $n$, $a_n = 1+\frac 1n \gt 0$ and thus $|a_n-L|\gt 0$.  Let $\epsilon = \frac{|a_n-L|}{2}$ for some even $n\ge N$.  Then $|a_n-L|\ge \epsilon \gt 0$ as required.
Therefore the sequence diverges.$\square$

**Part b)**

Suppose the limit $L$ exists.  Then for all $n\ge N$ for some $N\in \Bbb N$ and some choice of $\epsilon\gt 0$:

$$\left|\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}-L\right| =\begin{cases} |L| \\ |1-L|\end{cases} \lt \epsilon$$

But by the triangle inequality

$$1 = |1| = |1-L+L| \le |1-L| +|L| \lt 2\epsilon$$

which is clearly false for all $\epsilon\le \frac 12$.  Therefore the sequence divergences.$\square$

**Part c)**

We proceed similarly to part b.  Suppose the limit $L$ exists.  Then for all $n\ge N$ such that $4\mid n+2$ for some $N\in \Bbb N$ and some choice of $\epsilon$:

$$\left|-1+\frac 1{2^n}-L\right|\lt \epsilon$$

and for $n\ge N$ such that $4\mid n$,

$$\left|1+\frac 1{2^n}-L\right|\lt \epsilon$$

Therefore

$$2 = \left|-(-1+\frac 1{2^n}-L)+(1+\frac 1{2^n}-L)\right| \le \left|-1+\frac 1{2^n}-L\right| + \left|1+\frac 1{2^n}-L\right|\lt 2\epsilon$$

which is clearly false for all $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.  Therefore the sequence diverges.$\square$

Comment: Your proofs are all good.  With practice you can make them slicker and faster but you definitely have the right idea.

Comment: OK cool.  Thanks.